# Nifi - Dynamic attribute in the flow

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a dynamic attribute requirement.

Current Flow

```
1. GenerateFlow --> invokeHttp ( GenerateFlow is scheduled to run every 60 mins )
2. invokeHttp --> updateAttribute
```

I have stTime & endTime to invokeHttp which needs to be changed based on last invoke time.

Lets say, invoking http very first time,
stTime = 04-01-2023 00:00
endTime = 04-01-2023 01:00

In the next schedule, it should be,

stTime = 04-01-2023 01:00
endTime = 04-01-2023 02:00

I tried to set attribute in the generate flow like,

[image]

Using these attributes in invokeHttp.

[image]

Updating this in UpdateAttribute,

[image]

But, the stTime & endTime value remains same as it is there in the GenerateFlow when the next schedule gets triggered from GenrateFlow.

What is the best way to achieve this?
I want the newly updated value to be there even after the Nifi cluster restart or so.

One approach is to keep in Database and read from db before invokeHttp and update DB after invokeHttp.

Comment: If you need it after cluster restart - then you need a storage - file, database, persistent cache (like redis)

Comment: Yes, we have storage. Do we need to have anything specific in the flow to handle with the storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's imagine you have a redis as persistent storage. then following flow should work for you:

```
@startuml

GenerateFlowFile -right-> FetchDistributedMapCache
FetchDistributedMapCache --> UpdateAttribute1 : success
FetchDistributedMapCache --> UpdateAttribute2 : not-found
UpdateAttribute2 --> UpdateAttribute1
UpdateAttribute1 -right-> InvokeHttp
InvokeHttp --> PutDistributedMapCache
InvokeHttp --> RestOfTheFlow

GenerateFlowFile: run every 60 mins
FetchDistributedMapCache: get stored value
UpdateAttribute1: evaluate end-value
UpdateAttribute2: default start-value
PutDistributedMapCache: store end-value to be used\n as start-value

@enduml
```

[image]